# "poses" or "pose" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The activation and deactivation of features at
>   runtime poses challenges for ...

Is that sentence correct? Or does “activation and deactivation” require the plural, i.e., "pose"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either one works. You can view it as a single unified set of actions, as in

> Throwing and catching is a fundamental skill.
>   Breaking and entering is a serious crime.
>   Fish and chips is delicious.

Or you can view it as two separate actions:

> Throwing and catching are fundamental skills.

Comment: that was what confused me, that ultimately both work.

Comment: I'd upvote, Peter, but I'm sure we've been here before  – and you don't exactly need the points. Buy yourself a fish and 43 chips.

Answer (score 1):

Activation and Deactivation of features - This has two actions involved. Plural. So 'Pose' will be right.